# Simplest test for consistency of a rating scale

Tags: anova, ordinal-data, likert, rating

I want to explain to a non-novice doctor the best way to validate consistency of a measure across a likert-scale. The variable describes an average dose across 5 levels of patients (lower to higher). Whats the easiest way to validate that the dose statistically increases from level 1 to level 2 to level3 ..to level 5?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a contrast-type problem! Let's suppose you're assuming a linear increase between level 1 and level 5:

$L=c_{1}\bar{X}_{1} + \cdots + c_{5}\bar{X}_{5}$,

where $c_{j}$ are the coefficients, and $\bar{X}_{i}$ are the group means (the mean at level $i$)--you're computing the weighted group means. For a linear contrast, you might use the coefficients $-2, -1, 0, 1, 2$, as the coefficients must sum to zero. People usually evaluate these while conducting an ANOVA or related regression analysis. There's a general overview of the concept [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_%28statistics%29). I don't know what statistical package you're using, but, if you're conducting your analysis in R, you'll want to look at the contrast section in Julian Faraway's *[Practical Regression and ANOVA using R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf)*, which is both a great reference on the mathematics of what is happening, as well as how to actually use them in R.

Comment: Is there a statistical test that can check for the case of a linear contrast ? I check Faraways' book on how to do it in R and i was not able to find something.